# Ansible remove blank lines from list

Tags: ansible, jinja2

So I've got a playbook that retrieves the members of an AD group and gives me a list of their user IDs like this:

```
  tasks:
- name: Get group members
  set_fact:
    member: "{{ item }}"
  register: members
  with_ldap:
    - context: group_members
    - Jira_Administrators_GG

- name: Get userids
  set_fact:
    userid: "{{ lookup('ldap', '{{ item.item }}', context='users') }}"
  register: userids
  with_items: "{{ members.results }}"

- name: Create list of userids
  set_fact:
    userid_list: "{{ userids.results | map(attribute='ansible_facts.userid') | list }}"
```

Trouble is I end up with a few blank lines in the resultant list:

```
- name: Show userids
  debug:
    msg: "{{ hostvars['localhost']['userid_list'] }}"
```

Output:

```
TASK [Show userids] **************************************

ok: [xxxxxxxxx01] => {
    "msg": [
        "xxxxxxxxx55",
        "xxxxxxxxx58",
        "xxxxxxxxx71",
        [],
        "xxxxxxxxx46",
        [],
        "xxxxxxxxx27",
        [],
        "xxxxxxxxx63",
        "xxxxxxxxx27",
        [],
        "xxxxxxxxx04",
        "xxxxxxxxx87"
    ]
}
```

Does anyone know how to remove the blank lines from the list? I've had a look through http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#builtin-filters and tried a couple like `replace()` and `rejectattr()` in between the `map` and `list` but for whatever reason I'm not getting it right.

EDIT - Some attempts that didn't work...

I'm clearly not getting the syntax right with this one:

```
- name: Create list of userids
  set_fact:
    userid_list: "{{ userids.results | rejectattr('ansible_facts.userid', 'equalto', '') | map(attribute='ansible_facts.userid') | list }}"
```

..because the output was:

```
    An exception occurred during task execution. To see the full traceback, use -vvv. The error was: TemplateRuntimeError: no test named ''
fatal: [localhost]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "Unexpected failure during module execution.", "stdout": ""}
```

I then tried moving `rejectattr()` before `map`. This was better, it actually runs but doesn't seem to make any difference to the resultant list:

```
- name: Create list of userids
  set_fact:
    userid_list: "{{ userids.results | rejectattr('ansible_facts.userid', 'equalto', '') | map(attribute='ansible_facts.userid') | list }}"
```

I tried with `reject()` instead of `rejectattr()` like this:

```
- name: Create list of userids
  set_fact:
     userid_list: "{{ userids.results | reject('equalto', '') | map(attribute='ansible_facts.userid') | list }}"
```

...and like this:

```
- name: Create list of userids
  set_fact:
     userid_list: "{{ userids.results | map(attribute='ansible_facts.userid') | reject('equalto', '') | list }}"
```

I've tried a few permutations, I also tried comparing to `'[]'` instead of `''` because my empty lines show like that in the resultant list. I guess I just don't understand how to apply the filters correctly.

EDIT - Variable contents

Now if I do

```
- debug:
    var: userids
```

I get this (truncated to show 2 results that have userid populated and 1 with userid blank):

```
ok: [localhost] => {
    "userids": {
        "changed": false,
        "msg": "All items completed",
        "results": [
            {
                "_ansible_item_result": true,
                "_ansible_no_log": false,
                "ansible_facts": {
                    "userid": "xxxxxxxxx55"
                },
                "changed": false,
                "item": {
                    "_ansible_item_result": true,
                    "_ansible_no_log": false,
                    "ansible_facts": {
                        "member": "CN=Liam Fitzpatrick,OU=My User OU,DC=my,DC=domain,DC=com"
                    },
                    "changed": false,
                    "item": "CN=Liam Fitzpatrick,OU=My User OU,DC=my,DC=domain,DC=com"
                }
            },
            {
                "_ansible_item_result": true,
                "_ansible_no_log": false,
                "ansible_facts": {
                    "userid": "xxxxxxxxx58"
                },
                "changed": false,
                "item": {
                    "_ansible_item_result": true,
                    "_ansible_no_log": false,
                    "ansible_facts": {
                        "member": "CN=Mr Jones,OU=My User OU,DC=my,DC=domain,DC=com"
                    },
                    "changed": false,
                    "item": "CN=Mr Jones,OU=My User OU,DC=my,DC=domain,DC=com"
                }
            },
            {
                "_ansible_item_result": true,
                "_ansible_no_log": false,
                "ansible_facts": {
                    "userid": []
                },
                "changed": false,
                "item": {
                    "_ansible_item_result": true,
                    "_ansible_no_log": false,
                    "ansible_facts": {
                        "member": "CN=Mr Smith,OU=My User OU,DC=my,DC=domain,DC=com"
                    },
                    "changed": false,
                    "item": "CN=Mr Smith,OU=My User OU,DC=my,DC=domain,DC=com"
                }
            }
```

Comment: Bit harsh! I'd say I'm more stupid than lazy. Let me update the question with some examples of what didn't work...

Comment: I've x'd out the server name and user ids because I'm not allowed to share them publicly. `userid` is a fact set in the "Get userids" task. `userids` is the registered variable containing the list of user ids. `ansible_facts.userid` is how I retrieve the username from `userids.result`.

Comment: Why is there no account for Mr Smith? Is it a regular account, like other group members?

Comment: Do you mean why does that account have no samAccountName attribute? I don't know! I need to figure that out but at the time I was more interested in how to manipulate the list using Jinja2 filters than why it was like that

Comment: That's curing symptoms, not disease.

Comment: No it's learning. Thanks to Konstantin's answer I've learnt the difference between empty strings and empty lists. Thanks to your comments I've learnt that you're the kind of guy I'd avoid talking to in the pub.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a list of strings (e.g. `"xxxxxxxxx63"`) and empty lists (`[]`) – not empty strings.

You can use Jinja2 [select](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#select)/[reject](http://jinja.pocoo.org/docs/2.9/templates/#reject) filters, for example:

```
- name: Create list of userids
  set_fact:
    userid_list: "{{ userids.results | map(attribute='ansible_facts.userid') | select('string') | list }}"
```

P.S. and avoid nested curly brackets, use:

```
"{{ lookup('ldap', item.item, context='users') }}"
```

Comment: Thank you much!! That makes absolute sense. So if I did have empty strings `""` then maybe one of my `rejectattr()` attempts would have worked?

Comment: Yes, I guess so.

Comment: Please advise how to remove for empty strings like : "stdout_lines": ["", "D:\\Program Files\\Apache Software", ""]